# I want to export data in PDF file from firbase realtime database. I'm getting blank pdf file on button click

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, html5-canvas

I want to generate a PDF on button click with data that I get from the Firebase real-time database. I get data perfectly in the console with its key and value and try to append it in **ul li**. When I click the button, a blank PDF is downloaded. **I'm using jspdf library**. Can someone help me where is a mistake?

I want to generate a PDF on button click with data that I get from the Firebase real - time database.I get data perfectly in the console with its key and value and
try to append it in ul li.When I click the button, a blank PDF is downloaded.I 'm using jspdf library. Can someone help me where is a mistake?

```
function getPDF(e) {
    firebase.database().ref('gpr/' + e.id).on('value', function(snapshot) {

        function data() {
            for (const property in snapshot.val()) {
                var key = `${property}`;
                var value = `${snapshot.val()[property]}`;
                var ul = document.createElement("ul");
                ul.setAttribute("id", "tabledata");
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                var liTextNode = document.createTextNode(key + ": " + value);
                li.appendChild(liTextNode);
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }
        }

        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var text = data();
        doc.fromHTML(text, 15, 15);
        doc.save("output.pdf");

    });

}
```

Comment: Your `data` function doesn't return anything, so `text` is `undefined` after `var text = data();`.

Comment: How can i solve it ?

Comment: Make your `data()` function return the text you need.  We don't know what that is.